# The replica trick for interacting fields

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, research-level, entanglement-entropy

The replica trick is essentially a mathematical trick of the form:
$$\ln Z = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow 0}\frac{\partial}{\partial n}\ln Z^n$$
Intuitively, we think of making $n$ copies of a system (in my case i'm considering $Z$ to be a path integral of a field theory in the ground state) with branch cuts in the background geometry linking the $n$ copies together, with some boundary conditions. The entire construction seems to me to be entirely general and does not depend on the actual theory under consideration: I can in principle construct a replica surface for any theory I like (although solving the theory i.e. finding correlation functions might not be so easy).

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.0336.pdf), the authors state:

> A quartic interaction is not compatible with the replica trick

My question is this: Can anyone clarify why a quartic interaction is not compatible? Is my intuition off regarding how the replica trick works?
I understand that one must show that the path integral can be analytically continued to $n \in \mathbb{R}$ or $n \in \mathbb{C}$, does this have something to do with it?

Comment: I don't think they're saying that such an interaction is incompatible with the replica trick (which computes the limit of the partition function on an n-sheeted cover of the manifold), but rather that their method of computing this n-sheeted partition function by mapping to n decoupled fields on a torus is not valid. (i.e. that these fields are not decoupled when an interaction is turned on, if this method even still makes sense for an interacting theory).

Comment: I considered this, but the same author makes a similar, seemingly more general comment at http://bit.ly/2lp6Kd1 which reads 'Can we compute entanglement entropy for interacting fermions? For more general couplings, sine-Gordon is dual to
interacting fermions. Note however that the replica trick is
not compatible with the quartic interaction term.'